# Identification of LEGO set ... probably star wars ship? dark grey, black, transparent red, all angular

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I got 20 kg of LEGO bricks from family friend.

[image: dark grey, black, transparent red, all angular]

I found a lot of original sets, but these are still unknown.

Answer (score 5):

Based on

- Dark Bluish Gray Wedge, Plate 3 x 6 Cut Corners
- Trans-Red Plate 1 x 2
- Black Plate, Round 2 x 2 with Rounded Bottom (Boat Stud)
- Black Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on End (Horizontal Grip)

BrickLink only shows 1 set that has all of these

[75104-1 Kylo Ren's Command Shuttle](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75104-1)

[image: 75104-1 Kylo Ren's Command Shuttle]

Comment: It is the bottom part of the wing that is shown folded under.